# JQueryUI Spinners display correctly, but buttons and scrolling do nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, spinner

In my HTML I dynamically add number of numerical spinners that look like this

```
<input type='text' id='spinnerid' class='spinner' value='0'>
```

After they are added, I have

```
$(".spinner").spinner({step: 1, min: 0, page:10, numberFormat: "n"});
```

My problem is that when I load the page and click the button to add the spinners, they show up perfectly fine, with the correct value showing and with the arrow buttons, but nothing happens when I click the buttons or use the scroll wheel/page up/down keyboard buttons. I am able to edit the value by typing in the input box, but the actual "spinner" functions aren't working, and I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: The documentation mentions `numberFormat`'s dependency on the Globalize plugin, but sidesteps it by saying `if available`. Are you using `Globalize`? Does the code work if you do not specify the `numberFormat` option? Does the error console say anything?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I just tried removing `numberFormat` and the issue persists. Nothing shows up in the error console either.

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem in a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I had some interesting results doing so. I had a fiddle open from something that I had been working with before, so, not really thinking about what I was doing, I just popped the code into that one, and it worked fine. That fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/vDuxc/29/

When I actually made a new fiddle for this specific question, however, I couldn't get it to work. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/M82F7/

Comment: You did not include jQuery UI in your second fiddle (keep an eye on your console, it definitely says `$.ui` is undefined). Also, maybe not related, but images are failing for me in both fiddles.

Comment: My fault, I forgot to check jQuery UI. I've updated the fiddle to include it: http://jsfiddle.net/M82F7/1/

Curiously, the spinners work when the page up/page down keys are hit or the arrow buttons are clicked, but not when the scroll wheel is used. Also strangely, if I use certain other versions of jQueryUI in the fiddle, it no longer works.